# Excel: Is there an event to detect change in calculation mode (automatic/manual)

Tags: excel, vba, vsto

I would like code to run when the user or a macro changes the calculation mode from Automatic to Manual or Manual to Automatic. Is there an event that fires for this?

(The property is `Application.Calculation` in Excel interop.)

Using Excel 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event that fires for changing the calculation mode. About the closest you can get is to check at each calculation event.